# Why do my LWJGL fonts have dots and lines around them?

Tags: java, lwjgl, fonts

When we render fonts there are weird dots and lines around the text. I have no idea why this would happen. Here is an image of what it looks like:

[image]

Our font class looks like this:

```
package me.NJ.ComputerTycoon.Font;

import me.NJ.ComputerTycoon.BaseObjects.UDim2;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont;

public class Font {

    public TrueTypeFont font;
    private int fontSize = 18;
    private String fontName = "Calibri";
    private int fontStyle = java.awt.Font.BOLD;

    public Font(String fontName, int fontStyle, int fontSize) {
        font = new TrueTypeFont(new java.awt.Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize), true);
        //font.
    }

    public Font(int fontStyle, int fontSize) {
        font = new TrueTypeFont(new java.awt.Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize), true);
    }

    public Font(int fontSize) {
        font = new TrueTypeFont(new java.awt.Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize), true);
    }

    public Font() {
        font = new TrueTypeFont(new java.awt.Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize), true);
    }

    public void drawString(int x, int y, String s, Color color){
        this.font.drawString(x, y, s, color);
    }

    public void drawString(int x, int y, String s){
        this.font.drawString(x, y, s);
    }

    public void drawString(float x, float y, String s,  Color color){
        this.font.drawString(x, y, s, color);
    }

    public void drawString(float x, float y, String s){
        this.font.drawString(x, y, s);
    }

    public void drawString(UDim2 udim, String s){
        this.font.drawString((Display.getWidth() * udim.getX().getScale()) + udim.getX().getOffset(), (Display.getHeight() * udim.getY().getScale()) + udim.getY().getOffset(), s);
    }

    public String getFontName(){
        return this.fontName;
    }

    public int getFontSize(){
        return this.fontSize;
    }

    public TrueTypeFont getFont(){
        return this.font;
    }
}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Hi there. You've got multiple questions in your post, and here on StackExchange we'd prefer that you ask one question per post (as this is a Q&A site; see the [faq] for more details). I've edited your question to remove the first and last question, as they are the most under-specified. You can re-post them individually, but please take some time to read the Help Center's topics on good questions and provided relevant detail beforehand. It will lead you to much better answers.

Comment: Looks like the textures have artifacts from the surrounding characters in them (since the artifacts are the same for each instance of the letters, i.e. the `G`). Try adding more space between the characters in the bitmap file you're using for the font (along with adjusting the coordinates in the font description).

Comment: I don't think were using Bitmaps. I'm using Slicks org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont class.

Comment: `org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont` is really only a bitmap font internally, created from the font you give it. And from what I can see it has been deprecated in favor of `org.newdawn.slick.UnicodeFont`. Have you tried it?